# How to work BaseInlineFormSet inside Django form?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm so beginner in django so BaseInlineFormSet how to work i don't understand .

```
class BaseAnswerInlineFormSet(forms.BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        super().clean()

        has_one_correct_answer = False
        for form in self.forms:
            if not form.cleaned_data.get('DELETE', False):
                if form.cleaned_data.get('is_correct', False):
                    has_one_correct_answer = True
                    break
        if not has_one_correct_answer:
            raise ValidationError('Mark at least one answer as correct.', code='no_correct_answer')
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: BaseInlineFormSet how work ?